# Terragrunt using a sub-directory of a git as source

Tags: git, terraform, terragrunt

I am working on a multi-branch jenkinsjob that runs a separate stage for each micro-service, each with a terragrunt command based on a service.yaml

In one of the services both terragrunt.hcl and main.tf file are located in a sub-directory of the git.
(sensitive details have been censored with ???)

Here's the pipeline's directory terragrunt.hcl:

```
iam_role = "???"
remote_state {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    ??? [this definitely works]
  }
}
terraform {
  source = "git::ssh://gitlab@???.git"
  extra_arguments "bucket" {
    commands = "${get_terraform_commands_that_need_vars()}"
    optional_var_files = ["${get_terragrunt_dir()}/account.tfvars"]
  }
}
```

the git in question has a sub-directory named 'terraform' in which terragrunt.hcl and main.tf sits.

the command in jenkinsfile:
`sh "terragrunt plan-all --terragrunt-source-update --terragrunt-non-interactive --terragrunt-working-dir ${values.platform.<service-name>.config} --terragrunt-include-dir ${values.platform.<service-name>.folder}"`

and service.yaml as follows:

```
  node: ???
  region: ???
  <service-name>:
    config: "tfvars/<service-name>"
    folder: "terraform"
```

But this does not work. I get an Error that the directory is empty.
How do I make terragrunt look into the 'terraform' sub-directory?
Assume the git itself is immutable, I can't touch it.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Does this work?

  source = "git::git@github.com:acme/infrastructure-modules.git//networking/vpc?ref=v0.0.1"


https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#terraform